# Issue getting my form to reset via Jquery after submission

Tags: jquery, forms, email, reset

I am currently having an issue, i've looked through StackOverflow, w3c, and various other search options.
i've tried every option of javascript, jquery, and even php i can find and can't seem to get this form to reset after submission. code attached below, please help!

Form functionality:

```
$(function()
{
    function after_form_submitted(data) 
    {
        if(data.result == 'success')
        {   
            $('form#car-inquiry').siblings('#form-welcome').hide();
            $('form#car-inquiry').hide();
            $('#success_message').show();
            $('#error_message').hide();
            $('#car-inquiry')[0].reset();
```

lightbox close and open functionality:

```
if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
{
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('#car-inquiry').reset();
    container.fadeOut();
}
});

/* close form button*/
function closeForm() {
   document.getElementById("contact-car-form").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('#car-inquiry').reset();
   document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = "none";
}
```

Let me know if I can provide anything else of use. Thanks!

Comment: have you assigned some id to your form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign someid to your form and then trigger the reset event like this

```
 $('#form_id').trigger("reset");
```

or just refresh your page like this

```
 location.reload();
```

it will reset your form.

Comment: Yes, I tried this as well, still doesn't work, i'm not sure if my success and error are causing it not to function or what, where I have `$('#car-inquiry')[0].reset();` currently, i have tried every combination i could find to do it...to no avail.

Comment: @Andrew,changed the answer ,,,try this way it will refresh the page

Comment: You sir, are a saint and a scholar! thank you so much!

Comment: quick follow up, I added `location.reload();` to the bottom of my if statement...i am relatively new to JS and it isn't always easy to find solutions...with that in place now...how can i delay the display of the messages before the page reloads? Thanks!

Comment: didn't get you... display of messages

Comment: how can I add a timeout or delay to `$('#success_message').show();` so that it will display for a bit before the page reloads?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205729/discussion-between-ishwar-gagare-and-andrew).